# subtract data from a string

Tags: r, string, split

sorry for my poor English. I have a promotion campaign table likes below:

```
promotion_campaign <- data.table(product = letters[1:3],description = c('30-5,40-7,50-9','20-5,30-6,40-8','20-4,30-5,50-8'),tagged_price = c(30,21,52))
```

the 'description' means if tagged_price is higher than the first number before '-'(or equal to the number),it should get discounted by the number followed '-'. For instance,product a's tagged_price = 30, the actual price = 30-5 = 25. The campaigns are different from each product. The result table should be something like this :

```
promotion_campaign <- data.table(product = letters[1:3],description = c('30-5,40-7,50-9','20-5,30-6,40-8','20-4,30-5,50-8'),tagged_price = c(30,20,52),actual_price = c(25,15,44))
```

To get the 'actual_price' involves string split, lookup the tagged price to the right category and subtract the discount, anyone can enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` (`dplyr` and `tidyr` in particular) solution. Hope it's understandable. In any case, it's easy to execute it line by line to see what happens on each step.

```
library(tidyverse)
promotion_campaign %>% 
    mutate(description = strsplit(description, ",")) %>% 
    unnest(description) %>% 
    separate(description, c("price_point", "discount"), "-", convert = T) %>% 
    filter(tagged_price >= price_point) %>% 
    arrange(product, -price_point) %>% 
    group_by(product) %>%
    slice(1) %>% 
    mutate(actual_price = tagged_price - discount)
```

Comment: I like that this would generalize to varying numbers of discounts.

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
i1 <- as.integer(sub("-.*", "", promotion_campaign$description)) < 
                  promotion_campaign$tagged_price
m1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(promotion_campaign$description, 
                     '[-,]'), function(x) as.numeric(x)[c(2, 6)]))
promotion_campaign$actual_price <-  ifelse(i1, promotion_campaign$tagged_price - m1[,2], 
               promotion_campaign$tagged_price - m1[,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`, not `data.table`, and isn't easily generalizable if you have varying numbers of discounts, but it does answer your question.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
promotion_campaign <- data.frame(product = letters[1:3],description = c('30-5,40-7,50-9','20-5,30-6,40-8','20-4,30-5,50-8'),tagged_price = c(30,21,52))

promotion_campaign2 <- promotion_campaign %>% 
  separate(description,
           c("cut1", "discount1", "cut2", "discount2", "cut3", "discount3"),
           convert = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(actual_price = ifelse(tagged_price >= cut1, tagged_price - discount1,
                               ifelse(tagged_price >= cut2, tagged_price - discount2,
                                      ifelse(tagged_price >= cut3, tagged_price - discount3,
                                             tagged_price))))

> promotion_campaign2
  product cut1 discount1 cut2 discount2 cut3 discount3 tagged_price actual_price
1       a   30         5   40         7   50         9           30           25
2       b   20         5   30         6   40         8           21           16
3       c   20         4   30         5   50         8           52           48
```